# VS2017 SSIS Running from a Job error out when a Control Flow contains Script Task

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016, script-task

We are using `VS2017 (15.8.4) SSIS` running on `SQL Server 2016`.  Our package would run to completion within `VS` without error.  But when we use a `SQL` job that runs the package, it errors out immediately when the job starts.  I've even taken all the codes out of the `Script Task` and only has:

```
public void Main()
{
    // TODO: Add your code here

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
}
```

It would error out the same way.  If we remove the `Script Task` completely from the `Control Flow` and redeploy the package, the Job will run to completion with no error. The error from the `SQL` job history is very generic and has no useful information.  The `Script Task` does not give a compilation error when we saved it.

(1) Does anyone know why it error out?
(2) What would you suggest in configuring to get more informative error?
(3) Could it be due to missing DLLs or .NET Framework Components?

Comment: That script task code returns an error. If it works interactively but not in a job, 90% of the time it's one of two things: 1. The SQL Account doesn't have access to the required resources; 2. You are using local drive letters or resources that don't exist on the server.

Comment: Unfortunately the default error reporting for script tasks in SSIS is useless. First work out if you can do what you need without a script task. If not, add some error handling and reporting to it: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/709db169-8da6-4cee-bc6d-80081b5d2bc7/how-to-get-detail-error-description-of-a-script-task?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: What Target version is your SSIS project set too? See it under properties

Comment: TargetServerVersion is SQL Server 2017...
I was trying to force the package to error out but even when the script has:

Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;

It will still error out when I run from a Job.  I don't believe the script is ever fired off when I put is additional code to print.